Find the Nearest Connected Component of Interest in GraphDB
I'm working with a GraphDB repository that models components and their connections in an HVAC system. The graph includes many components that are irrelevant to my analysis (like ducts and bends). My goal is to find the nearest connected component of interest (e.g., a tee or damper) from a specified starting component.
I have explored the Shortest Path algorithm, which finds the shortest path between two given objects. However, I would like to treat the destination component as a wildcard, so I can locate the closest component of a certain type (specified with rdf:type), such as a damper.
Here’s the query I’ve attempted, but it only returns neighboring components regardless of their type:
PREFIX path: <http://www.ontotext.com/path#>
PREFIX inst: <https://example.com/inst#>
PREFIX ex: <https://example.com/ex#>

SELECT ?start ?end ?edgeIndex ?pathIndex
WHERE {
    VALUES (?src) {
        ( <src_node_URI> )
    }
    SERVICE <http://www.ontotext.com/path#search> {
        <urn:path> path:findPath path:allPaths ;
                   path:sourceNode ?src ;
                   path:destinationNode ?dst ;
                   path:pathIndex ?pathIndex ;
                   path:startNode ?start;
                   path:endNode ?end;
                   path:resultBindingIndex ?edgeIndex .

        SERVICE <urn:path> {
            ?start ex:connectedWith ?end .
            ?dst a ex:Damper .
        }
    }
}

